# How to Enable/Disable Magento 2 Developer Mode?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9

How can I hide errors from the main site?

My developer mode is off.

PHP `bin/magento maintenance:disable`.
What can I do? My site is not working.

By mistake, I run the command.

`php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

Now it is showing an error, and the overall site is not working.

Comment: add screenshot of error or add error in question

Comment: Can you add more details about the error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following commands :

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production

php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide an error on the screen then go to app bootstarp.php and change it to ini_set('display_errors', 0);

And also add error in your quetion.

Answer (score 1):

Run `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production` or `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set default`